# Remove repeated string from every column

Tags: awk

Trying to remove duplicates from each rows after ","

```
Input:
rs10993127  9:94266397-94266397,9:94266397-94266397 intron_variant,intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169,ZNF169
rs11533012  9:94267817-94267817,9:94267817-94267817 intron_variant,intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169,ZNF169

Desired output:
rs10993127 9:94266397-94266397 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169
rs11533012 9:94267817-94267817 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169

My codes:
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my code.

awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Instead of posting relevant code in comments, try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62712897/edit) your original post instead.

Comment: Can we always assume that each column will have a comma, or, if a column has a comma, that would be followed by a duplicate of what is before the comma?

Comment: Hi @DaemonPainter, yes, every column will have commas, and if the exact string comes after the comma, it is considered duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood a point here: the answer to "if a column has a comma, that would be followed by a duplicate" is _no_, correct? I read it fast and got it as a yes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below does not assume that duplicates are consecutive

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { 
         n=split($i,a,",");
         for(j=1;j<=n;++j) {
            s = s (a[j] in b ? "" : (s ? "," : "")  a[j])
            b[a[j]]
         }
         $i=s; s=""; delete b
     }}1' file
```

Which returns the output:

```
rs10993127 9:94266397-94266397 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169
rs11533012 9:94267817-94267817 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169
```

The idea in the above is to rebuild each field. Each field is split into various entries using `split` and stored in the array `a`. When rebuilding the field, we check if an entry `a[j]` has already been added to the new value `s` of the field. This check is done by validating if a key of the associative array `b` exists with the same value of the current processed entry (`a[j] in b`).

Comment: @austin7923, if this solves your question, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` and other implementations that support `\b`

```
$ sed -E 's/\b([^,]+),\1\b/\1/g' ip.txt
rs10993127  9:94266397-94266397 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169
rs11533012  9:94267817-94267817 intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant ZNF169
```

- `([^,]+)` match non `,`  characters
- `,\1` match `,` and text that was captured with `([^,]+)`
- `\1` also helps in replacement

Word boundaries are need to avoid partial matches, for example:

```
$ echo 'a bc,bcd 123,23' | sed -E 's/([^,]+),\1/\1/g'
a bcd 123
$ echo 'a bc,bcd 123,23' | sed -E 's/\b([^,]+),\1\b/\1/g'
a bc,bcd 123,23
```

If the column content can start/end with non-word characters like `:` then the above solution will not work if there are partial matches.

Comment: Is it not possible to say something like: `sed -E 's/\b([^,]+)(,\1){1,}\b/\1/g'` ?

Comment: yes, that'll help if there can be more than one consecutive duplicates

Comment: sed is not in the tags of the question

Answer (score -1):

One liner alternative based on the assumption:

```
awk '{output="";for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){split($f,a,",");output=output" "a[1]}print output}'
```

output:

```
 rs10993127 9:94266397-94266397 intron_variant ZNF169
 rs11533012 9:94267817-94267817 intron_variant ZNF169
```

known issue is that it happens a whitespace before the first field.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, probably due to the whitespace. Care on explaining?

Comment: Sorry, yes I can: The output is not the expected one. Each field can contain several different entries which are comma separated. Only the duplicates need to be removed. The solution presented here just prints the first entry.